# Boost asio GET with client certificate sslv3 hand shake failed

Tags: ssl, boost, boost-asio, client-certificates

I want to do a simple C++ web get similar to what is done by this curl command. I can use asio from boost. I must use boost 1.49

> curl https://mysite.dev/api/v1/search?q=test -k --cert
>   C:\work\testCert.pem

The server is requiring the client certificate.

I started by using this as an example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp

and I added modifications by adding calls to the context like

```
ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds);
ctx.use_certificate_file("C:\\work\\testCert.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
ctx.use_private_key_file("C:\\work\\testKey.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
```

My Request Looks like this:

> GET /api/v1/search?q=test HTTP/1.0
>   Host: mysite.dev 
>   Accept: */*

but I keep getting messages like this

> Error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

clearly there is a step I am missing in the handshake process

Comment: With client certificates you not only need the certificate but also the private key matching the certificate, i.e. you need [use_private_key_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/use_private_key_file.html) too.

Comment: But it works with the curl command without it? I did try using the private key also with the same results

Comment: The testCert.pem contains the private key, certificate, certificate issuer, certificate issuer issuer

Comment: So you are correct I needed the private key file specfied also, however I use the testCert.pem that contained both, for both they key and the cert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to disable SSLv3 support, appartently most servers disable this because of design flaws.

```
ctx.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds |
                boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 |
                boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3);
```

Comment: not a solution indeed, a workaround. you simply deactivate sslv3 possibility.